# Why does ''for item in "$list"'' only iterate once?

Tags: shell, loops, posix

I have this simple code:

```
#~/bin/sh

partitions="$(ls -1 /dev/loop?* | tr '\n' ' ')"
for partition in ${partitions}
do
  echo "A loop partition: ${partition}"
done
```

with output

```
A loop partition: /dev/loop0
A loop partition: /dev/loop1
A loop partition: /dev/loop2
A loop partition: /dev/loop3
A loop partition: /dev/loop4
A loop partition: /dev/loop5
A loop partition: /dev/loop6
A loop partition: /dev/loop7
A loop partition: /dev/loop-control
```

When I add quotes around the `${partitions}` var in the `for` loop (so that it becomes `"${partitions}"`) the output becomes different.

With Quotes:

```
#~/bin/sh

partitions="$(ls -1 /dev/loop?* | tr '\n' ' ')"
for partition in "${partitions}"
do
  echo "A loop partition: ${partition}"
done
```

new output:

```
A loop partition: /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop3 /dev/loop4 /dev/loop5 /dev/loop6 /dev/loop7 /dev/loop-control
```

**Why does do quotes impact the output in this way?**

I was told it is good practice to put `${vars}` in quotes in my shell scripts. Is this actually a bad practice?

Comment: Here's [shellcheck's explanation](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2066) for this issue.

Comment: To be clear, it's bad practice to store lists in string variables *at all*. If your variable were an array, `for partition in "${partitions[@]}"` would be the correct way to iterate over it. See also [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Why is there even a difference between having a list in a variable and having a list in, say, a file? Also @CharlesDuffy I try to keep POSIX compliance in my scripts; I tend to stay away from bashisms, and arrays are bash only (although also technically supported in ksh but...).

Comment: @Wimateeka, ...when you say "a list in, say, a file" -- a file with entries in the list delimited *how*? If you're using a line per item, that's unsafe for filenames -- filenames are able to contain literal newlines. The only safe way to store a list of C strings in a file, if you aren't going to escape or encode them, is to separate items with NULs.

Comment: @Wimateeka, ...that said, the thing that makes NULs suitable for that purpose is that it's the only character you *can't* have in a C string -- thus, can't have in a filename, so also can't have in a regular shell variable either. So if you want to read a NUL-delimited file's contents into a shell, what you need to read it into is... an array.

Comment: @Wimateeka, ...to describe what I mean by "unsafe", consider an untrusted user running `dir=$'/tmp/\n/etc/passwd\n'; mkdir -p -- "$dir" && touch "$dir/DELETEME"`; if someone with root were to run `find /tmp -name DELETEME | xargs -d $'\n' rm`, there goes your `/etc/passwd`. And that's if your admin is savvy enough to use the `-d` argument to `xargs` -- if they're not so savvy, even spaces can be used for that kind of attack.

Comment: @Wimateeka, ...a lot of extensions in ksh and bash exist for the sake of enabling correctness. It's not just sugar -- there's data that can't be safely handled at all in a reasonable baseline-POSIX script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you define `C string` for me? I tried googling myself and immediately got some savory NSFW images and `shell C string` didn't turn up anything helpful. (I'd like to save other readers from having the same google impulse that I did, especially on work computers).

Comment: @Wimateeka, a "C string" is as opposed to a "Pascal-style string", to use some really old terminology. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: (The worst data loss event I've been present for wasn't caused by a hostile attacker, but by a bug: A stay pointer in a library used by a Python script dumped garbage from memory into a buffer used for a filename, thus creating a file with a whitespace-surrounded `*` in a directory that "could only ever" contain files with valid hex digits; a cleanup script tried to delete the file without quoting the expansion, the `*` got expanded as a wildcard, and customer billing data was lost).

Comment: ...C strings are relevant here, because shell variables are C strings. Environment variables are C strings. Command-line arguments are C strings... and UNIX filenames are passed around at the operating-system layer as C strings. Thus, the innate bounds on what *can* be in one of those strings (as opposed to what's *expected* to be in one) are those provided by the underlying storage representation.

Comment: ...that said, `for partition in /dev/loop?*; do` might be the quickest POSIX-compliant way out of your immediate issue that doesn't involve string-splitting. Similarly, `find ... -exec sh -c 'for arg; do something_with "$arg"; done' _ {} +` provides a POSIX-compliant way to iterate over `find` output that doesn't rely on unquoted expansion (note that `{}` is *outside* the string parsed as code; that's critical).

Answer (score 3):

Using quotes prevents string-splitting (breaking items that have words in them into multiple pieces) and glob expansion (treating each piece as a pattern that can potentially match multiple filenames).

However, your original code *relies on* string-splitting, because it's storing `partitions` as a single string. Don't do that: Store lists in array variables, such that they retain separate identity even with string-splitting suppressed.

```
shopt -s nullglob                  # cause a glob with no matches to not generate any items
partitions=( /dev/loop?* )         # generate our list of partitions *as an array*
for partition in "${partitions[@]}"; do       # ...then iterate over "${array[@]}"
  echo "A loop partition: ${partition}"
done
```

The above is more efficient (it uses only tools built into the shell itself, which `ls` is not), and more correct (it doesn't split filenames with spaces into separate words, or replace globs found in names with additional filenames when such names exist).

Comment: What would be a way to solve this without using arrays?

Comment: `for partition in /dev/loop?*; do`

Comment: There are some other approaches -- f/e, you can use a function to store a glob, as in `with_partitions() { "$@" /dev/loop?*; }`, and then `with_partitions printf 'A loop partition: %s\n'`, but that kind of thing is generally pretty silly. There's a point when you're losing more time/effort/readability to all the hackery needed to write correct robust in baseline POSIX than the benefits that targeting baseline POSIX sh gives you.

Answer (score 2):

Putting quotes around a variable makes its value into a single word, even if it contains spaces. However, `for` iterates over the words in your variable. You've explicitly created a variable separated into words by spaces, and then turned off word splitting by adding the quotes.